# Modifying a datetime object

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a Datetime object that stores the date and time selected. The time defaulted to 12 AM and it is unchangeable unless you do it through code. I have another variable that actually  stores the time.

How would I modify the time in the Datetime object to store the time value that I have in another field?

Comment: “I have another variable that stores the actually time” What is the type of that variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the date portion of one to the time portion of the other:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now.Date;
DateTime time = DateTime.Now;

DateTime dateAndTime = date.Date + time.TimeOfDay;
```